# Dot product function: conflicting types error

Tags: c

I'm working on a function in C that returns the dot product of 2 vectors. Here is what I have:

```
int main()
{
   double vector1[] = {3.22,1.22,4.51,6.73};
   double vector2[] = {2.24,9.95,1.15,8.83};
   dot(&vector1, &vector2, sizeof(vector1)/sizeof(vector1[0]));
}


double dot(double * x, double * y, long int n)
{
   double product = 0.0;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      product = product + *x[i] * *y[i];
   }
   return product;
}
```

Finding the dot product in itself is a simple task, but I am stuck on a "conflicting types for dot" error that keeps coming up. I initially thought it was that sizeof(vector1)/sizeof(vector1[0]) was not a long int, but even after I made a long int variable called len and set it equal to sizeof(vector1)/sizeof(vector1[0]) it still did not work. X and Y are pointers and the function passes in addresses, so I think I did that part right. I'd really appreciate an extra pair of eyes to help me spot what I did wrong here. Thank you all!

Comment: It seems you have forgotten an important part of C when it comes to arrays. For example `&vector1` is a pointer to the array itself, and have the type `double (*)[4]`. You want a pointer to the first element instead, which is `&vector1[0]`, or plain `vector1` as that will decay to a pointer to the first element. You also seem to have forgotten another part, namely that you need to *declare* the functions you call, *before* you call them. Oh and you have forgotten the `size_t` type, which is the result of a `sizeof` expression.

Comment: Oh, and e.g. `*x[i]` is the same as `x[i][0]`. Which makes no sense. Which I believe your compiler will be giving you errors about. Are you asking about those errors? Or some other problem? Please [edit] your question to make sure you give us the details of your problem, and if it's about build errors or warning then copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a function dot before its definition. In C, you should declare a function before you use it unless you're defining it before the point of use. To fix this issue, you can declare the dot function before your main function, or you can define the dot function before the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double dot(const double *x, const double *y, size_t n);

int main() {
    double vector1[] = {3.22, 1.22, 4.51, 6.73};
    double vector2[] = {2.24, 9.95, 1.15, 8.83};
    double result = dot(vector1, vector2, sizeof(vector1) / sizeof(vector1[0));
    printf("Dot product: %lf\n", result);
    return 0;
}

static double dot(const double *x, const double *y, size_t n)
{
    double product = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        product = product + x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return product;
}
```

You can also simply move dot function above main function.

Edit: Revised the code as suggested. Also changed the dot function as static.

Comment: May I as a beginner will show you, lead software engineer, how the function should be declared?  It should be declared like double dot(const double *x, const double *y, size_t n); And within the function 1) the variable i should have the type size_t and 2) be declared within the for loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am not trying to rewrite the code, but simply update with the minimal touch to make it understandable for the person who asked the question. I appreciate your adjustments on the code, just like the compiler would warn and I would also not implement this code in this way.

Comment: Thank you! As you can probably tell, I am very new to C. I apologize for not realizing a mistake that could be fixed so easily and I'll be sure to avoid this mistake in the future.